# A question about kernel32.CreateTollhelp32Snapshot()

Tags: python, debugging

```
def enumerate_threads(self):
    thread_entry = THREADENTRY32()
    thread_list = []
    pid_list = None
    snapshot = kernel32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD,pid_list)    #why use self.pid 
    
    if snapshot is not None:
        thread_entry.dwSize = sizeof(thread_entry)
        success = kernel32.Thread32First(snapshot,byref(thread_entry))
        
        while success:
            if thread_entry.th32OwnerProcessID == self.pid:
                thread_list.append(thread_entry.th32ThreadID)
            success = kernel32.Thread32Next(snapshot,byref(thread_entry))
        kernel32.CloseHandle(snapshot)
        return thread_list
    else:
        return False
```

This code is refered by GRAY HAT PYTHON book.
I wonder why input `self.pid` at
`snapshot = kernel32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD,pid_list)`
instead of `pid list` in book
I think this code that I revise is right. But "self.pid" is operated too.
self.pid is a inherent value what be compared with thread list's PID
So how to operate `self.pid`?
I can't understand.

Comment: The book is too old  (April 15, 2009). It doesn't even work Python 3.11.x

Comment: It work Python 3.1. I did.